# Como usar UTF8 em JSON com PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, json, pdo

Estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco de dados sqlserver com PHP/PDO em seguida retorno um JSON para buscar em Angular JS.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($result);
print $json;
```

Porém, os valores que contém, por exemplo:

```
string(17) "Iniciou Inscri��o"
```

Em JSON ele retorna como `null`.  Minhas possíveis soluções, inclui:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Nenhuma delas resolveram. Alguém tem uma solução ?

Comment: expirmente inserir "inscri&ccedil;&atilde;o" em vez de "inscrição". Caso aconteça o que penso eu já lhe dou uma solução

Comment: Não consegui compreender. Estou buscando isso diretamente no banco de dados.

Comment: Sim eu sei, já tive esse problema também, é porque não deve estar configurado para utf-8

Comment: Então, eu altero isso diretamente no banco de dados ? Não é somente essa frase. São várias. No banco de dados está buscando certo, mas quando busco diretamente no php, ele traz com essas interrogações.

Comment: Basta um, para testar. nessa palavra mesmo, mude para o que eu lhe disse em cima

Comment: Não funcionou, ele me retornou inscri&ccedil;&atilde;o.

Comment: Parece que tem mesmo de `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` na sua base de dados, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009075/php-output-json-web-service-charset-utf-8-error

Comment: Estou usando PDO e esse comando não funciona no SQL Server.

Comment: Geralmente eu percorro o registro adicionando o valor em um novo array, onde o valor trato com utf8_encode. Isso ocorre pois a base de dados é ISO e o retorno do JSON e UTF8.